# Migrating code sign certs for android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder, code-signing

I have a code cert that is going to expire soon and have recently acquired a new cert from the same provider. I need to transition my android app from the older cert to the new cert. However because the certs are different android requires a full uninstall (deleting app data which I would prefer to avoid).

Due to my client specification I'm unable to use a self signed cert.

Is there a way to transfer without losing the local app data?

I am aware at `adt -migrate` exists but when I use it I get the following error

```
Migration certificate can only be applied to desktop native installers with native extensions.  Target: apk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to transfer without losing the local app data?

No, other than by backing up the data, uninstalling the old app, installing the new app, and restoring the data. If your app does not already have a full backup mechanism, then you are in a world of hurt, if you cannot get the CA to extend the certificate (per flx's answer).

> Due to my client specification I'm unable to use a self signed cert.

That does not change the fact that you need a signing key that will live long enough for the lifetime of the app. And, since certificate authorities do go out of business, so your client should buy a suitably-long certificate now, rather than assuming that an extension can be obtained at any point in the future.

Or, your client should come to its senses and use a self-signed certificate.

Comment: The app does have a backup facility but it's not automated, I may patch that in before the cert expires then push the new cert. But I think that may be my only option in this scenario as the CA is uncooperative.

Answer (score 1):

Extending certificate validity should be your first choice.

Let your CA extend your certificate instead of purchasing a new one. 
All certificate information will be preserved and your clients won't need to uninstall the app at all.

Comment: I agree, if I could take that option I would, the company who provides it hard codes the dates.